# How to solve the Mitov.Plotlab Scope control SetXYData() used in wpf throw AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, wpf, scope, access-violation, plotlab

I am used `Mitov.Plotlab` Scope control in WPF with `WindowsFormHost` element. So, when I changed the window size (the Scope control change else) with Use `SetXYData()` set many data on the Scope control, `AccessViolationException` has be throwed or the window crash exit.

Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Question be solved by Boian Mitov-The PlotLab Auther.
Because the PlotLab used non managed thread, is thread safe.
But we need to use non managed thread or UI thread set data.

1. this.dispatcher.Invoke
2. using TimingLab.ClockGen class import Mitov.TimingLabBasic.dll

   codeExample:
           ClockGen clockGen = new ClockGen();
           clockGen.Mode = ClockMode.FullSpeed;
           clockGen.Clock += ClockGen_Clock;
           clockGen.Start();

   ```
   private void ClockGen_Clock(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Do you data set 
   }
   ```